# Travis CI with Rails Not In Root Directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a Rails project setup with a directory structure that is this:

research/my_rails_app

with the research root directory having some helper scripts and other things that I want included under version control, but aren't a part of the Rails application itself. I want to have CI with Travis CI and the project is hosted on Github. I am a newbie to Travis CI so if this is a dumb question...please have some patience. My .travis.yml file is as follows:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 1.9.3
script: bundle rake rspec twitter_analysis/spec
services: 
  -mongodb
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database test-postgres_production;' -U test-postgres
gemfile:
  - /twitter_analysis/Gemfile
```

The error message when Travis tries to build is:

```
The command "psql -c 'create database test-postgres_production;' -U test-postgres" failed and exited with 2 during before_script.
```

Another is:

```
-mongodb: unrecognized service
```

And

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
```

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: There seems to be some confusion about how my app structure is laid out. My app is like this: research/twitter_analysis/ and then the .travis yaml file is located in the research directory! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and address what you should change one error at a time.

With the **first error**:

```
The command "psql -c 'create database test-postgres_production;' -U test-postgres" failed and exited with 2 during before_script.
```

Let's add the following to get a postgres database going on Travis CI:

```
env:
  - DB=postgresql
script:
  - bundle exec rake db:migrate
  - bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
  - bundle exec rake spec
before_script:
  - bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
```

Now that we're running a rake tast to create the database you should be able to remove what you currently had in `before_script:`

Now for the **second error**:

```
-mongodb: unrecognized service
```

I think you just need a space before the `mongodb` like so:

```
services: 
  - mongodb
```

And with the **third and last error**:

```
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
```

I haven't come across this myself before, but I've heard it occurs when your .travis.yml cannot be parsed. Double check that it is a valid YAML file, spelled correctly and in the right location. Can you confirm that it's in the root of the app and named **.travis.yml**?

Comment: I will try this and let you know how it goes! Thank you! Please see my comment above for where my travis.yml is. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. I think the location of the .travis.yml file will be causing the last problem. In my experience it's always in the root of the app where you'll find the app, config, db and subsequent Rails folders.

Comment: The .travis.yml does indeed have to be in the root of the directory, otherwise Travis won't pick it up.